# Displaying images with relative paths in the editor

Tags: images, pages

By default it seems the editor inserts images using an absolute path.

We're developing a site in /staging/ and plan to move it later on. Is there a way to get relative paths on images to display properly in the editor? Maybe there's a function or snippet in the editor that resolves to the upload path or something?

So for example, my images in my home page are:

```
<img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-21" title="Authentic Chinese Food" src="wp-content/uploads/2011/04/panel_authentic.jpg" alt="Authentic Chinese Food" />
```

which display fine on the page itself, but not in the editor.

Thanks!
John.

Comment: This is fine for pages, but if you prepare posts that will later be fed to RSS readers they need the full URL to display the image. When I migrate a site from staging to live I just replace the URL in the `post_content` column of the `wp_posts` table.

Answer (score 4):

I had a client ask for that and it took a little while to get it but its simple:

```
function change_mce_path_options( $init ) {
 $init['relative_urls'] = true;
 $init['document_base_url'] = get_bloginfo('url');
 return $init;
}
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'change_mce_path_options');
```

Comment: Not `home_url`?

Comment: depends on your settings, but i just hard code the site url with trailing slash `/`

Comment: Where does this code go? In functions.php?

Comment: This didn't seem to work in functions.php when I used relative paths on my images in tinymce.. any ideas?

Comment: Whats your URL? And what code are you using?

Comment: Can you elaborate on when this is triggered? If I have a site with images already inserted into posts, is this supposed to help with that or is it only for images after adding this filter?